# C# non-UI cross-thread invocation

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I'm trying to make cross-threaded calls in C#.

Whenever I invoke the methods of an object created in the context of thread A from a static method called from thread B, the method always runs in thread B. I don't want that, I want it run on the same thread as the thread A object whose methods I am calling.

Invoke works fine for UI calls and I've read dozens of articles and SO answers relating to different ways of making cross-threaded Forms/WPF calls. However whatever I try (event handling, delegates, etc) Thread A's object's method will always run in Thread B if it is invoked by Thread B.

What part of the library should I be looking in to solve this? If it's relevant, Thread B currently 'spins', reads from a network port and occasionally invokes Thread A's object's method through a delegate that was created in Thread A and passed in using a ParameterizedThreadStart.

I'm not looking to change paradigm, just send a message (a request to invoke a method) from one thread (Thread B) to another (Thread A).

EDIT:

My question was 'what part of the library should I be looking in to solve this?' The answer appears to be none. If I want to clearly delineate consumption and polling I'll have to write my own code to handle that.

Comment: Is thread A the UI thread or just another thread you have started?

Comment: I think you need to share code with us.

Comment: What does thread A do? Is it busy with something or somehow waiting? Why do you need exactly thread A to run your task if it is not the UI thread?

Comment: Objects don't run on a specific thread. Methods do.

Comment: @Albin Thread A is the main thread. It handles lots of different things and may be busy at any given moment performing various tasks or performing later UI actions. Thread B is just a spinner to grab data from a port.
@Beemer This doesn't seem a terribly peculiar scenario. Thread B gets some data, wants to pass it to Thread A so Thread A can work with it. I -could- post some code, but it's just 'make a new thread, spin and at some point call a method in the context of the original thread'

Comment: Given that Thread A is responsible for doing other things as well, I'd consider having a third thread C that handles the data gathered by B.  Since thread C has no other purpose than to process that data, have it suspend using an AutoResetEvent object until signaled by thread B that there is some work to be done.  Once it is done processing current data thread C can go back to being suspended until signalled again.  See my answer for more details.  If you don't want to make a third thread, you can work out some kind of flag that thread B can use to signal thread A; also suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I think you probably want to use the System.Threading.AutoResetEvent class.  The MSDN documentation has a decent example of one thread waiting on the other that I think is similar to what you are trying to do:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx
In particular, pay attention to the calls to trigger.WaitOne() and trigger.Set()

EDIT2:  Added option #3 after reading new comment from OP.

"Whenever I invoke the methods of an object running on thread A ..." - An object doesn't "run" on a thread and isn't really owned by any thread, regardless of what thread created the object.

Given that your question is regarding "non-UI cross-thread invocation", I assume you are already familiar with "UI cross-thread invocation".  I can see how WinForms would give you an impression that a thread owns an object and that you need to "send a message" to a thread in order to make it do something.

WinForm control objects are kind of a special case in that they simply don't function properly if you interact with them with a thread that isn't the one that created them, but that's not caused by the way that threads and objects interact.

Anyway, on to addressing your question.

First, a question to clarify the problem:  You've mentioned what Thread B is doing, but what is Thread A doing prior to being "invoked" by Thread B?

Here are a couple of ideas that I think are along the lines of what you want to do:

1. Don't create Thread A until you need to.  Instead of having Thread B "send a message to Thread A", rather have Thread B create Thread A (or call it Thread C if you prefer) and make it start executing at that time.
2. If you need Thread A to already exist and you only want Thread A to handle Thread B's events one at a time, you could have Thread A wait until it receives a notification from Thread B.  Take a look at [the System.Threading.WaitHandle class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx) (derived classes of interest are ManualResetEvent and AutoResetEvent).

   Thread A will at some point call WaitHandle.WaitOne(), which will cause it to pause and wait until Thread B calls WaitHandle.Set() on the same WaitHandle object.
3. If Thread A is busy doing other things, then you might want to set up some kind of flag variable.  Similar to the WaitHandle concept in #2, but instead of causing Thread A to pause, you just want Thread B to set a flag (perhaps just a boolean variable) that will signal to Thread A that it needs to do something.  While Thread A is busy doing other things, it can periodically check that flag to decide whether or not there is work that needs to be done.

Does the method that Thread A will execute on your object require any input from Thread B?  Then before Thread B calls WaitHandle.Set(), have it stick some data into a queue or something.  Then, when Thread A is "activated", it can retrieve that data from the queue and proceed to execute the object's method using that data.  Use a lock mechanism (i.e. the C# lock statement) to synchronize access to the queue.

Comment: Method 1 is feasible, just seems a rather odd way of handling it. Since I might have other threads performing the duties of Thread B, it wouldn't really work in future. As for method 2, I'll have to look but these seem to be exposing the kind of functionality I'm after. The crucial thing is that Thread A needs to run in real-time and cannot block or, worse, spin for more than [x] and the WaitHandle looks like covers that.

Comment: Still I'm very surprised .NET doesn't seem to provide a layer to handle this kind of interaction 'automatically' using the managed threads concept. UI threads obviously provide this, so why not other managed threads?

Comment: Rushyo, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/18/53041.aspx will give you information on various threading models. The vast majority of programs do not need to marshal back to the owning thread, and when they do it's quite a bit of work to manage this.

Comment: It's not the model that's the problem. It's that I expected .NET to facilitate the model I'm using, since it does so for its own 'UI thread' concept. I assumed it would expose some of that the code used in that model to non-UI threads. It apparently doesn't, so I guess I'll have to write it myself if I want to continue using that model - and I really do.

Answer (score 6):

> Whenever I invoke the methods of an object running on thread A

Objects don't run on threads.

In order for this to work, you will have to create some kind of queue you can shove a delegate into that will be routinely checked thread A's main loop.  Something like this, assuming that Something.MainThreadLoop is the entry point for thread A:

```
public class Something
{
    private Queue<Action> actionQueue = new Queue<Action>();

    private volatile bool threadRunning = true;

    public void RunOnThread(Action action)
    {
        if (action == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

        lock (actionQueue)
            actionQueue.Enqueue(action);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        threadRunning = false;
    }

    private void RunPendingActions()
    {
        while (actionQueue.Count > 0) {
            Action action;

            lock (actionQueue)
                action = actionQueue.Dequeue();

            action();
        }
    }

    public void MainThreadLoop()
    {
        while (threadRunning) {
            // Do the stuff you were already doing on this thread.

            // Then, periodically...
            RunPendingActions();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, given a reference to a Something object, you could do this:

```
something.RunOnThread(() => Console.WriteLine("I was printed from thread A!"));
```

Comment: Bad articulation on my part, but it wasn't my intention to use that terminology. However Thread A does lots of other things, including later UI invocations. My entire problem is I don't have a way to get my messages away from purpose-built thread that listens for things to something that can easily consume them. Thread A has much, much better things to be doing than spinning, which is why it wants the data from Thread B and doesn't just spin itself!

Comment: Well, then you will have to design a data rendezvous point for the threads that makes sense for your application.  Or provide us with a more meaningful question, since it lacks the detail necessary to provide a solution for your real problem.

Comment: Ok, let me put it in really C# terms: If I call FormA.Invoke(x), the .NET framework has functionality that allows it to ensure x is invoked on the same thread as FormA was created on. That does not happen for non-UI threads. I assumed I was missing something. Apparently not, they just simply left it out for non-UI threads. If that's the case, I'll write an equivalent abstract layer to do it.

Comment: I don't believe there is any such mechanism for non-Winforms objects.

Comment: This code is wrong. The most important part is missing: The event which is set by one thread and the other thread waits for it. Your code will consume 100% of a CPU!

Comment: @Elmue The example of that code is given in the last snippet in my answer.  Note that the comments in `MainThreadLoop()` are placeholders for other code that OP is running that would otherwise be occupying the CPU anyway.  If OP's code ever comes to rest for extended periods of time, then, yes, waiting on an event would be preferable.

Answer (score 3):

Code runs on threads. Objects aren't (generally - see thread local) bound to a particular thread. By doing WinFormControl.Invoke or WPFControl.Invoke, you are posting a message to the Message Pump or Dispatcher respectively, to run some code at a later date.

The message pump is something like this:

```
Message message;
while(GetMessage(&message))
{
    ProcessMessage(message);
}
```

Microsoft has specifically built their UI controls and projects to allow the posting of messages across threads. Calling a method from thread A will always execute that method on thread A, even if it ends up doing some kind of asynchronous work and returning early.

Edit:

What it is I think you need is the Producer Consumer pattern.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy12yx1f(VS.80).aspx

Forget about consuming the messages from your main thread, which is what it sounds like you want to do. Consume from thread C.

Thread A is doing 'much more important things'. Thread B is spinning, listening for messages. Thread C is consuming those messages.

No need for marshalling across threads.

Comment: As I said, microsoft purpose built the mechanism that allows cross thread messages for UI components. Nothing exists natively for non-ui cross thread messages without attempting to reimplement a type of message pump. Why do you want to execute a delegate on a different thread anyway?

Comment: It does seem that way, yes. It's just so surprising to me, is all. Thread B is spinning, permanently, looking for network traffic. Not that unusual I think. Thread A is a huge data consumer which deals with lots of messages from different sources. Every other message it consumes is abstracted such that the code that is executed in thread A doesn't even know how it is consuming it, various libraries and layers are handling it and passing through events. I want Thread B to behave the same way for consistency and to avoid Thread A code's bloating with stuff that isn't in its purpose at all.

Comment: The other advantage of using Thread B, rather than simply binding and listening in Thread A, is that Thread B will want lots and lots of execution time gifted by the OS. That is naturally assigned at a thread level. Indeed, Thread A may want this too at various points. The two strands of code will be fighting over resources and it's easier to just let the OS take care of that by assigning thread priorities.

Comment: With regards to your edit: It's not a question of how it gets the data, it's the model it uses to acquire it. I want a model that allows my code, as executed by Thread A, to be a really dumb consumer of data and offload the work of polling for that data to another piece of code, also run by Thread A. I hoped .NET the 'other piece of code' for me. If my code starts worrying about polling then it becomes exponentially more complex - I'd love to just dump that on something else, even if I have to write my own library to do it, that's fine - I just naturally assumed .NET would do it.

Comment: I do understand what it is you're trying to do. I asked a similar question not too long ago. See stackoverflow.com/questions/2083326/ and the problem is re-entrancy if you want to stop what a thread is doing and execute some other arbitrary code. Or, requiring every thread to have some kind of message pump which would be horrible design. A thread is useful for set-and-go tasks. If you need to pass messages to a specific thread, it's not a whole lot of work implementing a consumer as other answers suggested

Comment: Not a whole lot work but the consumer model creates code that needs to consume AND poll. I really don't want the code to be handling its own polling. I want it to behave in the same way a form does, where that is abstracted off somewhere else. I've completed such a framework this morning, anyway, and it appear to gel very well with other stuff running on the thread. The code just invokes the polling system's interface, which neatly co-exists with the other polling methods on the thread by handing back to the kernel. Happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're going to have to do is roll a sort of Queue and have Thread A watch that queue for work.  When Thread A sees new work enter the queue, it can dequeue it and do the work, then return to waiting for more.

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
    public class ThreadAQueue
    {
        private Queue<delegate> _queue;
        private bool _quitWorking;

        public void EnqueueSomeWork(delegate work)
        {
            lock(_queue) 
            {
                _queue.Enqueue(work);
            }
        }

        private void DoTheWork()
        {
            while(!quitWorking) 
            {
                delegate myWork;

                lock(_queue)
                {
                    if(_queue.Count > 1)
                        myWork = _queue.Dequeue();
                }

                myWork();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The purpose of Thread A is to consume messages. If it is spinning, listening to messages it's no different to Thread B.

Comment: What is Thread A doing while there are no messages to consume?  Other things as well, or is that it's sole purpose?

Comment: I would rather it just picked up the message at an abstract level than jumping between its own work and checking for external work (even if that's what it would be doing in the framework anyway, it seems hugely inelegant to always have it going back to spinning after everything when there's concepts like event handling about - and spinning is quite inefficient anyway). I mean, why bother listening for a port on another thread? I could just have one giganto-thread that handled everything. And I could just forget about having a multithreading OS and write a whole messaging system from scratch.

Comment: @Dr. Wily Other things. Handling C# events, handling drivers events, listening to processes, checking for data on network ports. The first three are handled neatly by the OS/Framework.. it just seems arcane to do the latter without their help. Thread B was created to handle the fourth messaging system and I want to abstract that as far away from Thread A as possible, preferably offloading the messaging work onto the OS/Framework. It's not that Thread A couldn't have its own messaging system, it's that I don't see why it should be directly responsible for it when theres a powerful OS behind it.

Comment: I really find it difficult to imagine that the .NET framework has this functionality for UI threads but doesn't expose it to other threads, just 'because'. I don't see it as Thread A's job to pull messages, I believe it should have them pushed like UI cross-threading invocation where there's a layer that takes care of it.

Comment: @Rushyo, I agree with you, having a generic message-handling framework would be cool; sounds like a good candidate for a third-party tool. I don't think it's surprising, though, that this isn't provided by the .NET framework; I think that this is only possible with UI threads not because of any innate functionality provided by threads, but rather because it takes advantage of messaging functionality of the Windows GUI. Since that functionality is tied to the OS GUI, one can't take advantage of it if not working with an OS window handle.

Comment: The thread is just a means of executing code, what you're looking for is a very specialized thread.  If I were just wanting to run a quick (but complex) math calculation on a background thread to keep my UI from freezing, I dont want that thread firing up a message loop and all kinds of queuing logic.  The TPL (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) has better constructs for handling the kinds of you're looking to do here (although it's not a message queue).

Comment: @Dr. Wily It's a shame it's less powerful than the kernel API in a lot of ways. I mean, I'm not advocating Asynch Proc Calls, but there's still of stuff .NET doesn't give you.
@CodingGorilla .NET 3.5 unfortunately. Had to re-implement a lot of .NET 4.0 functionality.

Comment: CodingGorilla: Your code is wrong. The funcion DoTheWork() will consume 100% of a CPU. You are missing the most important part in your code: The event that is set by one thread and the other thread waits for it.

Comment: @Elmue It was not intended to be a full implementation, it was intended to express the idea, hence I referred to it as 'psuedo code' (although I mispelled that as sudo, that's fixed :) )